# Unity crash caused by EmguCV

Tags: unity-game-engine, emgucv

I have an error with my program where unity is crashing after trying to run this function. The function is to convert Texture2D to Image

```
void SetTextureDefault()
{
    try
    {
        Texture2D currentTexture = new Texture2D(CameraTexture.width, CameraTexture.height);
        currentTexture.SetPixels(CameraTexture.GetPixels());
        currentTexture.Apply();

        // Asuming leftBackground and rightBackground of Image<Bgra, byte> exist

        if (leftBackground == null || rightBackground == null)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(currentTexture.EncodeToPNG()))
            {
                leftBackground = new Image<Bgra, byte>(new Bitmap(ms));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rightBackground.Bytes = leftBackground.Bytes = currentTexture.EncodeToPNG();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Debug.Log(err.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Unity (both editor and stand alone application) just crashed and not showing any error. Only showing this [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Hbg.png).

I can only think about memory access violation (but the application not showing any exeptions)

If i remove the function, the program will run normally

I'm using Unity personal with EmguCV (desktop version).

Answer (score 0):

The problem that causing the application to crash is:

```
leftBackground = new Image<Bgra, byte>(new Bitmap(ms));
```

The problem solved after building a new dll containing the function and attach it to unity and worked.
Weird...